# Java - Using a scanner input to repeat a pattern

Tags: java

I'm writing a program for a class assignment where a box shaped pattern must be made using for loops.  The pattern is then repeated horizontally a certain number of times based off of a scanner input.  For example the scanner input is 3 so the pattern is repeated three times horizontally.

I have created the pattern and have the scanner set up.  How to I get the scanner input to repeat the pattern?

Not asking for code just a push in the right direction...

Comment: "must be made using for loops", so use for loops?

Comment: in for loop ` i < scanner input `

Comment: wrap you logic inside a for loop as @FastSnail mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<Integer.valueOf(scannerInput); i++) { // where scannerInput is the String input that is obtained from user
    printPattern(); // System.out.println() call
}
```

Comment: Thanks mcw, my issue is that each time I compile and enter a scanner input I get only one of the pattern boxes to print.

Comment: If you want your pattern to print X times, you set your for loop to iterate X times (read into how for loops work if you need to). Then, simply put your print pattern in your for loop code block { } just as I have done in my above code.